# Why a single element list is taking two inputs and then giving out of range error?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

The code below consists of a List having only one element but on running,        it is taking two inputs and then giving an error rather than giving an error after first input. Why?

```
def ani():
    sales = [0]  
    index = 0   

    print('Enter the sales for each day')

    while index < 5:
        print('Day #', index + 1, ':', sep='', end='')
        sales[index] = float(input())
        index += 1

    print('Here is the values you entered')

    for value in sales:
        print(value)


ani()
```

Comment: When `index = 1`, `sales[index]` would give you that errors. `sales` is a list of length 1. Use `sales.append(float(intput()))` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously your traceback would have told you that the error is on this line:

```
sales[index] = float(input())
```

It succeeds on the first pass through the `while` loop because `index` is `0`.  On the second pass through the loop, `index` is `1` but since the right hand side of expressions are evaluated before the left hand side, it still asks for input.  Once the input is read, the execution resumes (first `float` gets evaluated on the right and then the left hand side gets evaluated).  When the left hand side is evaluated python finds out that the list doesn't have a "slot" available to put the data so it raises an `IndexError`.